# Syntax error at JSX tag

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, package.json

I'm receiving a syntax error when I run "npm run build-dev", which triggers "browserify". That should convert my JSX tags in my JSX document (below), but it's just throwing a syntax error at the opening tag. I'm really struggling to see what's wrong here, I can't find any differences between this and another project that I did recently.

Node.js versions tried: v9.7.1, v8.9.4
npm versions tried: v5.7.1, v5.6.0

My HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            @keyframes example {
                from { background-color: red; }
                to { background-color: yellow; }
            }
            div.main {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: red;
                animation-name: example;
                animation-duration: 4s;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="doc"/>
        <script src="page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "AnimationTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Learning how to use CSS animations with JS/react triggers.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-js": "browserify index.js -t babelify -o page.js",
    "build-js-dev": "browserify index.js -d -t babelify -o page.js",
    "build-dev": "npm run build-js-dev",
    "build": "npm run build-js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "."
  },
  "author": "D. Scott Boggs",
  "license": "AGPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^15.2.0",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

My index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AnimationTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("AnimationTest constructor reached.");
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("AnimationTest.render: Beginning rendering of document root");
    return (
      <div id='main'/>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <AnimationTest />,
  document.getElementById('doc')
);
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Also, please provide the contents of your `.babelrc` file - you have the React preset installed for Babel, but it seems like it's not getting used.

Comment: I think you have to use `<div id="main"></div>` instead of `<div id="main" />`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was missing .babelrc. I added

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

to my-project-folder/.babelrc and now it compiles without error. Thanks.